# Java Implementable Class Creation?

Tags: java, user-interface, implementation, game-engine

So I want to make a game engine, and I instantly realized that stuff has to be "auto-imported". For example, when you `implements Runnable`, you get an error because it HAS to have the `run()` method in the class.

How do you do this? How would i have a class, when implemented, FORCE a method, and then automatically run this method?

An example, usable when answering:

I have a Frame class. This frame class will, when implemented, ALWAYS use a method, in the class that implemented it, named `draw()`, and will HAVE to be implemented to use the frame class. Example code:

```
public class test implements HFrame {
    // constructor
    public test() {

    }

    // method called when test is run
    public static void init() {
        HFrame f = new HFrame(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        f.display(); // makes the frame visible
    }

    // method that frame will always call when it is implemented
    public void draw() {
        // stuff to draw
        new Circle(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

using the comments, how would i get this to work?

thanks for the help, and i apologize if this isnt worded the best...

Comment: Isn't this exactly what interfaces are for?

Comment: p.s. is static in "public static void init()" a typo?

Comment: i just use init by habit, could be any name. otherwise, what do you mean?

@RichardTingle, i'm not quite sure what you mean...

Comment: Well static is associated with the class itself, not the instance of the class. You can't impliment a static method from an interface, it just doesn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to "force" a class to implement certain methods you use an interface, an example of which is below

```
public interface GameEngineInterface {
    void init();
    void draw();
    Vector3d annotherMethod(Object object);
}
```

Any class that is going to be used by your Game engine would implement the GameEngineInterface engine.

GameEngine methods would work as such

```
public Object someMethod(GameEngineInterface anyObjectThatImplementsGameEngineInterface){
    //method body
}
```

The GameEngine then doesn't care about the specifics of the implimenting methods, just that it can call those methods.

Comment: ok, so the `void draw();` makes it look for and run the draw method in the implementing class?

Comment: The draw method does whatever it is defined as doing in the implimenting class (much like the run method), the interface mearly promises that (a) it exists, (b) it takes no arguments and (c) it returns void

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface with the methods that you want to run.  All the classes that will be used must implement that interface.  This is exactly how `Runnable` works:  `Runnable` is an interface with one method `void run()` that the Thread can call to execute the runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to implement the [Template Method design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). In your example, `run` would call `draw()`, which must be implemented in the concrete class.